# Express API wont take any requests from POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, express, postman, middleware

I have been trying to develop an API for use in a MEAN stack application. The API handles user registration and authentication.
What's been really funny is that it has not been taking any requests from Postman. Even a simple '/' get request with a response will not work. The error I get on postman is as below

My index.js is as below:

```
const exp = require('express');
const bp = require('body-parser');
const { success, error } = require('consola')
const { connect } = require('mongoose');

// Bring in the app constants
const { DB, PORT } = require("./config");

// Initialize the application
const app = exp();

// Call the middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bp.json);

// User Router Middleware
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/users"));
app.use("/basic", require("./routes/basic"));

// Connect to the database

const startApp = async () => {
    try {
      // Connection With DB
      await connect(DB, {
        useFindAndModify: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
      });
  
      success({
        message: `Successfully connected with the Database \n${DB}`,
        badge: true
      });
  
      // Start Listenting for the server on PORT
      app.listen(PORT, () =>
        success({ message: `Server started on PORT ${PORT}`, badge: true })
      );
    } catch (err) {
      error({
        message: `Unable to connect with Database \n${err}`,
        badge: true
      });
      startApp();
    }
  };



startApp();
```

My basic routing is as follows, it itself will not even work for me:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!' + req.body)
  })

module.exports = router;
```

The postman response is as in the screenshot below:

[image: Postman Screenshot]

The server does appear to be running but is just refusing all requests it seems.

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/node-auth


 SUCCESS  Server started on PORT 3000                                                 16:26:36
```

Comment: What is the error status code? please provide picture with error details

Comment: what did you get on `localhost:3000/`  ?

Comment: You are calling app.use(cors()); but cors function is not imported. [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: Where is your get router defined? `/` inside the router doesn't mean `http://localhost:3000/` on postman.

Comment: The router is defined at the start of the file like "const router = require('express').Router();"

Comment: localhost:3000/ is just timing out and saying Error: socket hang up

Comment: @BlackMath It is defined in the index.js and then also at the start of the basic.js file. Is there another place it should be defined.

Comment: If you have it in the index.js before the routes you need to use `app.get` and not `router.get`, in which case the mounted routes won't be hit. I suggest to remove it from index.js while keeping it in basic.js and in postman try `http://localhost:3000/basic` with a get request.

Comment: It's `app.use(bp.json());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies.

I was missing a () brace which was allowing the application to run but not correctly. Sometimes all it takes is another eye.

Before:
`app.use(bp.json);`
After: `app.use(bp.json());`

Working perfectly now.

Comment: Please don't post typo answers; if possible, simply remove the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you import express in your basic router ? 
it should look like this :

```
 const express = require("express");
 const router = express.Router();
  
 router.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.send(`Hello World! ${req.body}`);
 });
          
 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hi, it is imported, yes. const router = require('express').Router(); But still not working

Answer (score -1):

You are not using **router** from the same express instance in index.js